# Buttons centered over canvas

Tags: html, css, button, html5-canvas, centering

I have 4 overlapping canvases (acting as layers) positioned absolutely and centered horizontally and vertically.

Over this canvas, I want to overlay four HTML/CSS buttons in a column in the center of the canvas (for a game menu). I'm new to CSS and HTML and I haven't been able to figure out how to get the buttons centered over the absolutely positioned canvas. How can I do that? Thank you.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas0" width=800 height=600></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas1" width=800 height=600></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas2" width=800 height=600></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas3" width=800 height=600></canvas>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#canvas0,  #canvas1, #canvas2, #canvas3 {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}

#canvas0 {
    z-index: 0;
}

#canvas1 {
    z-index: 1;
}

#canvas2 {
    z-index: 2;
}

#canvas3 {
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Edit:

Here is a drawing of what I would like to know how to do. Buttons that stay centered on the center of the canvas, no matter how the browser is resized.

[image]

Second edit:
If I settle for horizontal centering (instead of insisting on both vertical and horizontal centering), I can do it very nicely.

This article helped me very much: [Absolute Positioning Inside Relative Positioning](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)

Here is my final code, and a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FV2NL/) demo.

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <canvas id="canvas0" width=800 height=600></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas1" width=800 height=600></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas2" width=800 height=600></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas3" width=800 height=600></canvas>
        <div id="menu">
            <button id="button1" type="button">Start</button>
            <button id="button2" type="button">Options</button>
            <button id="button3" type="button">High Scores</button>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#cavas0 {z-index: 0;}
#canvas1 {z-index: 1;}
#canvas2 {z-index: 2;}
#canvas3 {z-index: 3;}

#menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: 4;
    top: 200px;
    left: 275px;
}

button {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;   
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
}

#button1 {
    left: 25px;
}

#button2 {
    left: 25px;
    top: 75px;
}

#button3 {
    left: 25px;
    top: 150px;
}
```

Comment: I would not recommend using 'absolute' layout, rather relative. Absolute layout will cause huge issues later on when you begin to add more ids and classes to your body.

Comment: NebulaeGuy, is there an alternative? I couldn't get the canvases to overlap each other AND be centered without using absolute positioning. And every solution I found online instructed me to use absolute positioning. If you know to have centered, overlapping canvases using relative layout, I'll start a new question about that, because I think that's information that should be out there.

Comment: Z-index will do you wonders!

Comment: Oh wait you already use that. One moment let me think.

Comment: You can position components with relative layout, just use 'top, bottom, left and right'. This will fix most issues that could occur when using absolute. Sorry I cant give you the proper answer as I am unable to code as I'm on my phone. Also in regards to creating another question, I wouldn't recommend it, you'll probably have it removed for same/similar questions.

Comment: Okay, thanks I'll try it. And I meant that I would start a different question unrelated to buttons: how to center overlapping canvases with relative positioning (since I've never seen, in my searches, information about that online)

Comment: I see, good luck with your program and I hope someone can provide a better solution than mine.

Comment: Here is a update on the answer. Like @NebulaeGuy said, position:absolute is not brilliant, but from what you asked for this should sort you out.

Comment: Sorry, I have been out all day. You could from what you have shown in your edit, use `@Media screen and (max-width: 1000px)` to have it stay as the resolution changes. I will type this for you once I get home.

Comment: I don't understand what's different with the solution of your edit. It didn't stay in the vertical center.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. In my edit, the buttons stay locked on the center of the canvas at all times. Even when the window is resized, the buttons don't budge from the center of the canvas. They behave as if they are actually part of the canvas. That way, I don't need to create my own GUI for my canvas game. I can use HTML.  

The canvas itself is also centered horizontally on the page.

At least that's how it appears on my computer, using Firefox, Chrome, and IE.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something along the lines of this.

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mg4JE/) for a demo

append this css

```
.buttonContainer{
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left:45%;
    width:80px;
}
.class='but' {
    float:left;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas0" width=800 height=600></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas1" width=800 height=600></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas2" width=800 height=600></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas3" width=800 height=600></canvas>
    <div class='buttonContainer'>
        <input class='but' id='but1' type='button' value='Button 1'>
        <input class='but' id='but2' type='button' value='Button 2'>
        <input class='but' id='but3' type='button' value='Button 3'>
        <input class='but' id='but4' type='button' value='Button 4'>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You forgot to add a DEMO link.

Comment: Dude have you really check your fiddle link. its blank?

Comment: My bad, sorry. its there now.

Comment: Thank you. But I found a problem... If the browser window is too small and there are scroll bars, then the buttons are no longer centered on the center of the canvas.

Comment: I will sort it out once I get home, for you, Kheema

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed your issue, now that i am finally home from my day at Thorpe Park. Basically... i took @Morne nel's code and changed `top: 250px;` to `top: 40%`. I'm not sure if this is mathematically centered, but you can always do that yourself. Nonetheless, the buttons stay in the position relative to the `canvas`. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Blah</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <canvas id="canvas0" width=800 height=600></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas1" width=800 height=600></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas2" width=800 height=600></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas3" width=800 height=600></canvas>
    <div class='buttonContainer'>
        <input class='but' id='but1' type='button' value='Button 1'>
        <input class='but' id='but2' type='button' value='Button 2'>
        <input class='but' id='but3' type='button' value='Button 3'>
        <input class='but' id='but4' type='button' value='Button 4'>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
#canvas0,  #canvas1, #canvas2, #canvas3 {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}

.buttonContainer{
   position: relative;
    top: 40%;
    left:45%;
    width:80px;
}
.class='but' {
    float:left;
}


#canvas0 {
    z-index: 0;
}

#canvas1 {
    z-index: 1;
}

#canvas2 {
    z-index: 2;
}

#canvas3 {
    z-index: 3;
}
```

JFIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/Th3JT/

Here is what it looks like on my monitor with a resolution of 1080x1920:

[image: Larger window]

[image: Smaller window]

Obviously (as can be seen in JFiddle), the buttons are not mathematically centered on different resolutions. However, to fix this you just have to do the maths and use media queries. Give it a try and contact me in a while if you are unable to fix it. You can always hit me up on Skype for some voice help and I can always use TeamViewer to help you further. I really hope I fixed most of your issues (Atleast when the window changes, the buttons stay in the center of the window). I believe that the reason that it is not mathematically centered on different resolutions could be due to the canvases using `position: absolute`. Play around with it and hit me up with any problems that you encounter and I'll try to help you as best I can. Good luck with your programming, and don't forget your caffeine when coding ;).

Comment: Thank you for your very thoughtful response. I'm a little confused because in your jsfiddle, the buttons seem to stay centered in relation to the window, not the canvas. I wanted them to stay centered on the canvas. But I very much appreciate your help. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, I must have misunderstood the question a tad. Never mind I'm glad you found a solution.