# HTML5: How do you place a fixed Text Input over a centering canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, centering, textinput

I have a canvas that contains a game. I want to place an html text input field at a specific spot in the game. This is proving difficult since I want the canvas to automatically center horizontally in the window and it desyncs with the text input when the window size changes.

What style settings should I give both elements to make the text field remain in the same place on the canvas?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle with some sort of example we could work with?

Comment: Wrap both the canvas and the input-type-text in a div. The wrapper is `position:relative` and the canvas & input are `position:absolute`.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the canvas or the input to center if their position is absolute.

Comment: I don't have any code set in stone yet. Anything that will make the canvas centered with the text input remaining in the same spot on the canvas will work. But here's my working attempt:

http://jsfiddle.net/3n6k7jz7

If I set the text field to absolute then it won't center, but if I remove the position: absolute then it doesn't appear over the canvas and goes below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that works: http://jsfiddle.net/FV2NL/

```
<div id="container">
    <canvas id="canvas" width=800 height=600></canvas>
        <div id="menu">
            <button id="button1" type="button">Start</button>
            <button id="button2" type="button">Options</button>
            <button id="button3" type="button">High Scores</button>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Everything has to be inside of a div group that has relative positioning and is centered with margin: 0 auto;. The canvas should have absolute positioning and top: 0; left: 0;. The text inputs are absolute and put inside of a relative div.

This is from another StackOverflow page here:

[Buttons centered over canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24730944/buttons-centered-over-canvas)

Answer (score 0):

Give your canvas element position:relative and give your message element position:absolute. Then use top & left to position the message.

```
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position:relative;
}


#message {
  position:absolute;
  top:150px;
  left:100px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ebkpcsvg/1/

Comment: The canvas isn't centered in this solution though. How do I make the canvas center in the page horizontally but keep the message on it?

Comment: You can centre the canvas horizontally by adding a containing div and then using the css property: margin: 0 auto. Here i have changed the fiddle to make the message absolutely positioned to the containing div
https://jsfiddle.net/ebkpcsvg/2/

Comment: This almost works, but when the horizontal scroll bar appears then the text input slides off target again.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately there are other problems too. I don't want the text input at exactly left: 50% and top: 50%. But if I change these values to put it where I want it, it is no longer in sync with the canvas at all.

Comment: @Eagleheart is there other content inside the containing div for the canvas? Do you mind producing a jsfiddle?

Comment: I found a solution that works on another stack overflow page here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24730944/buttons-centered-over-canvas

I'll post it in another answer. Thanks for the help!